# Android How to know if the user is inactive

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

In my App, I have some Fragments which call another fragment in a tree-like structure.

I'd like to bring the user back to the Home page when he isn't touching anything for some time (the 30s probably).

I thought about creating a handler in the activity which handles all the fragments, every time the user interacts with something I can consider him "Active" and I participate the handler for other 30s.

In case the handler reaches the 30s, I bring back him to the Home fragment.

So, the actual question is: How can I get a listener for every element of my activity, so that I can participate the handler when I get a click?

If you need some of my code ask me to post it.

Comment: you can use onTouch or onUserInteraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback for **key**, **touch** or **trackball** events in Android is `onUserInteraction()`. Override this method in your activity. It will catch most of the common touch events & you can use your handler in the callback.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();

    //Your Handler update code

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement touchlistener to the container you are adding fragment. On Touch Reset your handler wait count 30 then do your actions.

```
  (frgamentcontainerView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                //set your handler
            }
            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: can you please explain with the code, without code, this should be go as a comment